# Does a Facebook game HAVE to be a canvas app?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, web, facebook-canvas

I would like to build a small website which features a gaming element using FB login and Open Graph.

If I wish to use the Achievements API, Scores API and timeline aggregations reserved only for games, does my "website" HAVE to operate within the FB canvas?

Can I declare a FB app as a "website using facebook login", but place this in the "Games" app category?

Ideally I would like to use my own domain outside of FB canvas. Reading the developer documentation this is unclear.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook app is just a website ! You can design the website/app and deploy it in your domain. Then create a new facebook app and just fill the details of your domain in the CANVAS URL . That's it. You can choose your own unique facebook app URL when you create a new app in facebook.

How it works is, when the users goes to your app in facebook Ex- apps.YOUR_APP_NAME.facebook.com , facebook will redirect only the CANVAS area of the App to your domain.

Comment: Okay thanks, is this technique permitted? or is it a bit of a grey-area redirecting users away from FB when they follow a link to an app?

Comment: Hey, only facebook would redirect canvas area in the app to your Domain. ! Just goto https://apps.facebook.com/ and try creating a new app. you'll get cleared.